# Depth sensing camera recommendation?

Tags: ros, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For getting started with depth sensing in ROS-Industrial I want to purchase a depth sensing camera which is supported in ROS.

I am searching a depth + RGB camera. Therefore the Xtion (only depth) is not a solution. The Xtion Live is not available (at least in EU/ Austria).

Therefore the only solution seems to be the Kinect 1? Unfortunately it is very old and I need a adapter + power supply for connecting it to USB.

Is there any tip for a technically better camera?

Thanks
RockOn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222454/depth-sensing-camera-recommendation?/) by [RockOn_23](https://answers.ros.org/users/25322/rockon_23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are multiple RGBD cameras supported by as many ROS drivers/nodes (see [wiki.ros.org/Sensors - 3D Sensors](http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors#A3D_Sensors_.28range_finders_.26_RGB-D_cameras.29) for an incomplete listing), but the Kinect v2 is a popular one. Well supported by [code-iai/iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) and [ethz-asl/kinect2-ros](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kinect2-ros).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RockOn_23](https://answers.ros.org/users/25322/rockon_23/) on 2015-12-14**:
thx. I also think that the kinect 2 seems to be the best available depth + RGB camera at the moment

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-15**:
Well, that will depend on what your metrics are, I think. There are many rgbd (like) devices that have better accuracy / robustness, but also higher cost fi. I just know that there have been some successful applications in ROS-Industrial using Kinect2's, which is why I mentioned it.